# LFTP: CLS with folder size

Tags: ftp, ls, lftp

When using CLS to list files via LFTP, is there a way to show the calculated size of any folders that appear in the listing?  Here's what I'm using:

```
cls -s -h --sort=date
```

And here's the result:

```
3.7G bigfile.mp4
4.0K some.folder/
4.0K another.folder/
1.1G anotherfile.psd
```

All folders are showing as being only 4.0K, which of course does not reflect the total size of the folder's contents.  My Google-fu fails me on this one :/

Answer (score 2):

**cls** shows folder size reported by the server. In this case it is the size of the folder itself without the size of nested files. To see the size of all nested files and directories, use **du -h** command.